# Hierarchical logging in Emacs Lisp

Tags: logging

What is the right way to perform hierarchical logging in Emacs Lisp?

As a representative example…

```
(scoped-message
 "baking cake"
 (progn
   (scoped-message
    "making batter"
    (progn
      (scoped-message "whisking eggs" (whisk-eggs))
      …))
   …))
```

I would like to see something like `baking cake → making batter → whisking eggs` in the Messages butter and in the mode line.

Is there a library, macro, or standard idiom that makes this easy?

The library `straight.el` does this when building dependent libraries (e.g. `building org-drill → org-contrib`), but it's built in a very custom way. Is there a standard solution available?

Comment: I do not see a big need for such a library since the effect is easily obtained by `let`-binding: `(let ((scoped-message "baking cake"))  
 (let ((scoped-message (concat scoped-message " → making batter")))  
   (message (concat scoped-message " → whisking eggs"))))` Pityingly the line ends are lost in the comment and therefore the structure information associated with the line ends is lost. Nevertheless it is more a comment instead of an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Noting that this is more or less along the lines of how `run-mode-hooks` and `delay-mode-hooks` interact, you could do something similar to that:

```el
(defvar scoped-message-p nil)
(defvar scoped-messages nil)
(defmacro scoped-message (message &rest body)
  (declare (indent 1))
  `(progn
     (if scoped-message-p
         (push ,message scoped-messages)
       (setq scoped-messages (list ,message)))
     (let ((scoped-message-p t))
       ,@body)
     (unless scoped-message-p
       (message "%s" (mapconcat #'identity (nreverse scoped-messages)
                                " → ")))))
```